# Haskell type system explanation?

Tags: haskell, types

I cant get my call to the function to compile. All the commented calls
are failed attempts. Please advise, also is there any good explanation
of Haskels type system out there??

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
import Data.List

--isInt:: Fractional a => a -> Bool
isInt x =
   x == fromInteger (round x)


doForm :: (Integral int, Fractional int) => int -> int -> Bool
doForm cube n =
         isPrime (divide - n)  
   where divide =   cube / (n^2) 



main =
   -- print $ doForm (12^3 8)
   -- print $ doForm (12^3::Integer 8::Integer ) 
   -- print $ doForm ( fromIntegral 12^3 fromIntegral 8)
   -- print $ doForm (toInteger 12^3 toInteger 8)
   -- print $ doForm (toInteger 12^3 toInteger (8) )
   -- print $doForm (round 12^3)  ( round 8)
   -- print $doForm (floor 12^3)  ( floor 8)
   -- print $doForm ( 12^3::Fractional  8::Fractional)
   -- print $doForm ( 12^3 8)::Fractional
   -- print $doForm (12^3 :: RealFrac 8::RealFrac )
```

Comment: A side note: you're not calling your functions correctly. In Haskell, we write `function arg1 arg2 arg3`, and **not** `function (arg1 arg2 arg3)` like you've written here. If you use the second method, it will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no types in the `Prelude` which are instances of both `Integral` and `Fractional`, so you will need to pick one or the other constraint and stick with it. You can convert with functions like these ones:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b -- Num is a superclass of Fractional
floor, ceiling, round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b -- Fractional is a superclass of RealFrac
```

You may also want to carefully consider whether you want `(/)` or `div` for division.

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
div :: Integral   a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: Or possibly a `quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`, and perhaps convert with `truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`. Subtle differences.

Answer (score 0):

[`Integral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) and `Fractional` not only aren't overlapping in the standard library, but form a contradiction in terms. [Integral(2)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/integral) states the number has no fractional part (coming after a decimal point), while [fractional(1)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fractional) states it may. This is one sort of property described by the type classes.

In the case of a [`Fractional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac) type, you can check if the fractional part is zero using something like:

```
isInt :: RealFrac a => a -> Bool
isInt n = snd (properFraction n) == 0
```

[`RealFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac) states that the number is both fractional and [real](https://www.mathopenref.com/real-number.html). [`Complex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex) numbers support division but don't have a single definition for fractional part.

Considering you want to check if a number is prime, and only positive integers can be prime, we could choose to reduce the test to only handling integral types:

```
doForm :: Integral int => int -> int -> Bool
doForm cube n = case remainder of
             0 -> isPrime (quotient - n)
             _ -> False
   where (quotient,remainder) = cube `quotRem` (n^2)

main =
    print $ doForm (12^3) 8
```

A number being positive or non-negative is another property one might have expressed in a type system (for instance, [Ada has ranged integers](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html)), but Haskell's prelude does not. [Haskell report section 6.3, standard Haskell Classes](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#sect6.3) lists the type classes in standard Haskell. Other packages might extend this, for instance [nat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/nat-0.3/docs/Data-Number-Int.html) provides positive and non-negative integers and [NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty-0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) provides non-empty lists.